# Android: Camera.Open() returns null with one Project but Not the other. Same Device

Tags: android, android-camera, android-permissions

I am learning the Android Camera Api and i am testing it on a Nexus 6 device. I downloaded a Camera Api tutorial which runs fine on the device. I then created my own project and essentially copied the code but that one always returns null whenever i call Camera.open(). The code is virtually identical.

The Manifests are also identical and so are my gradle files.

But the tutorial i downloaded from the website works while the one i created from Android Studio does not.

I cant figure out what i am doing wrong.I have checked the previous questions regarding this issue and i am not making the same mistake. The Manifest permissions are in the proper location (above the application tag), the Nexus 6 has a back camera so no camera is not an issue.

**Non-Working Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.gr3ymatter.cameraapidemo">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Non-Working MainActivity:**

```
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private ImageSurfaceView mImageSurfaceView;
    private Camera camera;

    private FrameLayout cameraPreviewLayout;
    private ImageView capturedImageHolder;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        cameraPreviewLayout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
        capturedImageHolder = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.captured_image);

        camera = checkDeviceCamera();
        mImageSurfaceView = new ImageSurfaceView(MainActivity.this, camera);
        cameraPreviewLayout.addView(mImageSurfaceView);

        Button captureButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        captureButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                camera.takePicture(null, null, pictureCallback);
            }
        });
    }
    private Camera checkDeviceCamera(){
        Camera mCamera = null;
        try {
            mCamera = Camera.open();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mCamera;
    }

    Camera.PictureCallback pictureCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
            if(bitmap==null){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Captured image is empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
            capturedImageHolder.setImageBitmap(scaleDownBitmapImage(bitmap, 300, 200 ));
        }
    };

    private Bitmap scaleDownBitmapImage(Bitmap bitmap, int newWidth, int newHeight){
        Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, newWidth, newHeight, true);
        return resizedBitmap;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**Non-Working SurfaceView Class**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Created by Afzal on 2/2/16.
 */

public class ImageSurfaceView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private Camera camera;
    private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;

    public ImageSurfaceView(Context context, Camera camera) {
        super(context);
        this.camera = camera;
        this.surfaceHolder = getHolder();
        this.surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        try {
            this.camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            this.camera.startPreview();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        this.camera.stopPreview();
        this.camera.release();
    }
}
```

The Working Projects files are the same as i literally copied them while i was following the example. I can paste a github link to both working and nonworking projects if that would help?

EDIT: Here are repos for the two projects
https://github.com/Gr3ymatter/CameraApiDemo_Working
https://github.com/Gr3ymatter/CameraApiDemo_NotWorking

EDIT: LOGCAT output. Also based on Madhurs helpful comments i thought maybe this is a device issue, so i ran this on the Nexus 7 but i still got the same issue.

[image]

Thank you in advance for the help!

Answer (score 2):

You need to ask permissions in nexus 6 because of Android 6.0
check for more info on [permissions](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

OR you can change in manifest to,

```
//make target lower then 23 then it will run properly in android M
    <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="15"
            android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
```

Example without permissions

Check this example hope it helps,

https://github.com/pikanji/CameraPreviewSample

YOUR CODE IS WORKING FOR ME

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Unfortunately doing that didnt change anything. Whats confusing is that the working project has the same permissions as mine.

Comment: dude see the targetsdk in manifest and complied sdk in gradle it should be under 22 and also check in the project which worked

Comment: I checked. I have also posted the repos of both project here so that you can see for yourself. The manifest and gradle files are identical and above 22. Both are set to 23. 
https://github.com/Gr3ymatter/CameraApiDemo_NotWorking
https://github.com/Gr3ymatter/CameraApiDemo_Working

Comment: i had some time so i checked your code and its working perfectly i will share a screenshot of it in my answer

Comment: Madhur, Thank you so much for your time. That is very interesting. I wonder why it is not working on my nexus 6..I updated the answer with a screenshot of the logcat output that i get in the NOTWORKING code. I keep getting null for the camera object. Notice the package name is the same. I dont have any such issues with the working code. At first i thought maybe the camera wasnt released properly and might be busy but it works without fail in the working code. Weird.

Comment: Okay i just saw that in your main xml layout add **<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>** at top before relative layout

Comment: Did not make a different :(. Both versions now have the xml version tag. I even tried removing it from both main_activity.xml files and still the same deal. One works the other doesnt. Thank you again for your help.